# what make an access database work faster on a local network?

Tags: database, frontend, backend, ms-access-2016, local-network

I have created an access database with 200.000 records in three tables. The size of the database is only 95 MB. I have put the backend on a computer (core i7, 4GB ram, 500GB hard). I have linked the backend to 6 frontends on 6 other computers (clients) in a local network. there is a search-form in the frontends includes a search-as-you-type search-box.

The problem: While several clients use the search-form at the same time, the database works very slowly, even sometimes the search stops.

My question: Is that a software or a hardware problem?

Concerning hardware: Do I need to change the server computer to a better one? What computer parts affect this? Harddisk? Ram? CPU? Other?

Comment: A Microsoft Access database is not intended for being used by multiple users concurrently. You should consider hosting your data on some a database server (SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc.)

Comment: Generally the simplest and most cost-effective way to make an Access database faster is to replace it with SQL Server. SQL Server Express is a free edition and some effort has been put in by Microsoft to give you tutorials and background material on how to migrate (while still keeping Access as a front-end, should you so prefer). Access is pretty neat for single-user setups, interface-wise, but it does *not* scale. The earlier you prepare to migrate, the less trouble you'll have in the future.

Comment: For a short-term solution: search with `WHERE myColumn LIKE 'searchstring*'` and make sure the column has an index. If you need a full text search `WHERE myColumn LIKE '*searchstring*'`, see the previous comments.

Comment: I would strongly advise against using Access for a database that has 200k rows of data. Access is a great toy for simple things and also for learning about databases; It's not intended for serious or heavy use, and it's reliability is questionable (you can lose data). With this amount of information, you should switch to SQL Server (paid) or to PostgreSQL, MySQL, or MariaDB (all free).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I had a client who asked about SQL Server Express and off the top of my head I couldn't tell if the free version (SQL Server Express) has some limitations that could affect a small database. Is it realistic to switch from Access to SQL Server Express (for free) and be able to host a small database there?

Comment: @TheImpaler: absolutely. Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15) the limits of Express are basically 1) no more than 1 CPU/4 cores (more is unused), 2) no more than ~2 GB of memory used for caching data, 3) the DB size can't exceed 10 GB. Even with these limits in place Express is far more capable than Access, especially since advanced features like in-memory OLTP, data compression and columnstores are still available (and there is simple paid upgrade path to Standard should you hit the limits).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Those limits vastly exceed what this client needed. Too late now for the recommendation, but I'll keep it in mind. Thank you.